# Understanding Use of If Err.Number

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a vba macro which takes info from an excel sheet and populates a word document.  In the beginning of the macro I used code I found to define the variables for the word document/application.

```
Dim WRD As Object, DOC As Object
On Error Resume Next
Set WRD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set WRD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

' Setting the correct word document template

Set DOC = WRD.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\template.docx", ReadOnly:=True)

WRD.Visible = True
```

This all works very nicely however I am trying to fully understand the code that I am using and I don't know why I have

```
Set WRD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set WRD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
```

I've looked up what the `Err.Number` is but why is `WRD = CreateObject("Word.Application")` used twice with it.

Comment: [Err object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/err-object)  `I've looked up what the Err.Number is but why do I have it twice right here?` Twice? I only see it once?

Comment: I'm sorry I mistyped that, I meant why is it used with ```WRD = CreateObject("Word.Application")``` twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is incorrect. It should be:

```
Dim WRD As Object, DOC As Object
'ignore errors to prevent generic error message being displayed
On Error Resume Next
'attempt to get the currently open instance of Word
Set WRD = GetObject(,"Word.Application")
'If Word isn't open an error is generated
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'as Word wasn't already open create a new instance
    Err.Clear
    Set WRD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
'reset error handling as errors should not be ignored
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Oh I see, so the initial one is looking for a currently open word document but will throw an error if one is not open.  Then the second one creates the new word document?

Comment: @JoshL - Not quite. The first is looking for an open instance of the Word *application*. The second creates one, though it won't be visible on screen at that point and won't have any documents open.

Comment: Oh so that's where the difference of document and application come in.  Thank you!

Comment: @JoshL - `CreateObject("Word.Application")` is the equivalent of starting Word from the command line using the /n switch. Startup switches are explained [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/366399/how-and-why-to-start-microsoft-word-from-the-command-prompt/)

Comment: @JoshL - I have edited the answer to correct the missing comma from `GetObject`. For the sake of completeness I have also added `Err.Clear`, though it isn't essential.

Comment: It is. And put it, please, in front of the line `Set WRD = CreateObject("Word.Application")` and followed by `On Error GoTo 0`. If there is no Office installed, or it is but without Word, or something else (wrong) would happen, it would be good to know that the session has not been created. Anyhow, an error will be raised when the object will be used...

Comment: @FaneDuru - As `On Error GoTo 0` is required after the block if, would you also add it within the block? TBH I don't use late binding when coding across Office apps as IMO there is nothing to be gained by it.

Comment: Only to let the code return an error in the above enumerated cases... It is not a must, it is only a good to be, I would say.